# How to hide a construction site without hindering the workers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

Let's say you have a building site that could fit in a roughly 100 feet square. And you want to hide it without hindering workers.

Now you could use the *mirage arcane* spell to hide the building but, a.) the workers would not be hidden, and b.) even the workers would not see the building (which seems counter-productive).

Or, you could use *Mordenkainen's private sanctum*, which would hide the build site in a not at all conspicuous 100 feet square fog (insert sarcasm sign here).

With the above considered: can you use *hallucinatory terrain* to hide the fog, by making the original terrain there?

- If yes, how would that work for the workers?
- Or could you create a terrain that hides the fog and is even more
  inconspicuous?
- Or am I thinking too much into that and there is a completely
  different approach to this?

Is it even possible to do this in D&D 5e?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Are you looking for magical solutions only? When you say hide, can something else appear to be there, or should it look like normal unclaimed land?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide it?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 While I do not look for magical solutions only, I do look for solutions a wizard might come up with ;). And yes Something else can appear to be there, but it would be preferable if it is or at least resembles the original terrain. e.g. a ship is being repaired near a cliff and would like to hide it from people who look down from the said cliff, or a tower is erected in a valley and would not be seen from the entrances of said valley.

Comment: @goodguy5 I am trying to hide it so nearby populace, and possible monsters would not get alerted until it is done.

Comment: would a large rock or some other formation be sufficient?

Comment: and what level is the wizard in question?

Comment: @goodguy5 It would be sufficient if it is explainable by the surroundings, like a landslide or a fallen cliff part hence "inconspicuous", however, it has to be larger than the sanctums cloud to cover it entirely, and workers should be able to work in it. Not sure what happens if the hallucinatory terrain covers the sun for example, would it be dark in the build site would light in the build site escape the terrain or the sanctum?

Comment: @goodguy5 this is mostly a theoritical question to see if it is possible and how, so it can be as high as 20, although such high level wizard has probably already stopped adventuring :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Multiple upcast Major Images

If you're a Wizard with 6th level slots, you can conjure up a permanent illusion with [Major Image](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Major%20Image#content).

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible phenomenon that is no larger than a 20-foot cube. The image appears at a spot that you can see within range and lasts for the Duration. It seems completely real, including sounds, smells, and temperature appropriate to the thing depicted.

You can cover your building and workers with the illusion of a mountain, large trees, or whatever else you can think of. I drew an illusory tree over a tower in construction, to give you an idea of what I mean.

[image]

It doesn't hinder your workers, who just need to interact once with the illusion to see through it.

> Physical interaction with the image reveals it to be an Illusion, because things can pass through it. [...] If a creature discerns the Illusion for what it is, the creature can see through the image, and its other sensory qualities become faint to the creature.

Depending on how big your building is, you can cast multiple Major Images to cover everything up.

> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 6th level or higher, the spell lasts until dispelled, without requiring your Concentration.

Just find a way to prevent other on-lookers from physically interacting with the Illusion and it should be hidden from most people. Keep a few Lore Bards around to use their Bardic Inspiration Die to subtract from any nosy onlooker's Investigation Check.

Comment: Won't the workers interacting with the illusion (by being inside of it) make it clear to onlookers that it's not real?

Comment: They must be covered by the illusion. Like a big rock that keeps them and the building from the sight of anyone outside. I've added that to my introduction paragraph

Comment: Gotcha - so they're deep enough inside the illusion that their movement isn't seen disrupting it? I'm not sure I'm 100% on board, but I get it.

Comment: Can you make a major image in front of an object and project on it what is behind said object? e.g like a tv screen and a camera linked? if so this could work, although it would need quite a few slots to do.

Comment: @Veronika I don't think so. You can change the look of the illusion with your action if you're within range, but it's not the same.

Comment: @NautArch Come. Join me inside the tree. It's cozy :D

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Oh so it is a still image. Or is it somewhat programmable, like waves of sea or grass flowing with wind? I am not trying to exactly copy whats behind, just inserting a gif of seafoam would suffice...

Comment: @Veronika You can make it change appearance (for example, an illusion of a creature can carry on a conversation). Read the spell description for more info, and talk with your DM. Illusion spells are very much in the hands of DM regarding their power :P